# What is the operator `.*` doing in matlab?

Tags: matlab

Let's say given 2 vectors:

`a = [1;2;3], b = [4;5;6]`.

The operaton `a*b` is not acceptable because of matrix multipiclation definition.

But I can see that `a.*b` is acceptable and resulting `[4;10; 18]`.

What is the `.*` operation doing?

[Tried to google but no result](https://www.google.co.il/#q=.%2a%20in%20matlab)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Element-by-element multiplication

Comment: make it an answer, luis

Comment: @LuisMendo In this example, [1*4, 2*5, 3*6]? Element by element of both matrecis?

Comment: @user1798362 Yes, exactly

Comment: @user1798362 See http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/matlab_prog/array-vs-matrix-operations.html

Comment: Who have downvoted? what is wrong with my question?

Comment: @user1798362 I have. Sorry, but this is too basic Matlab. A downvote in StackOverflow means "This question shows no research or effort..."

Comment: Use the built-in help in MATLAB: just type `help .*` or `doc .*` (they do different things, try them both)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does element-by-element multiplication. Quoting Matlab help (or see [online help](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/times.html)):

> .*  Array multiply. 
>       X.*Y denotes element-by-element multiplication.  X and Y
>       must have the same dimensions unless one is a scalar.
>       A scalar can be multiplied into anything.

For more information see [@am304's link above](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/matlab_prog/array-vs-matrix-operations.html).

Comment: Thanks!! I have another question, why is `a'*b = 32`? Why is turns a scalar and not a vector?

Comment: Because `'` is conjugate transpose. So now you have a 1x3 matrix times a 3x1 matrix, which gives a 1x1 matrix according to matrix multiplication rules

Comment: Yes, you are right .. I forgot a bit how to multiplay a matrix. Thank you for this help! Have a good day.